# Basis vectors in different coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, change-of-basis

Consider the point P(1,1,1). In cylindrical polar coordinates, this can be expressed as $\sqrt(2)e_r$ + $e_z$ . I am unsure as to why it cannot be expressed as $\sqrt(2)e_r$ +$\frac{\pi}{4}$ $e_{\theta}$ + $e_z$? May someone explain why this is not the case?